# Resizable Vue.js Side Panel: Keeping a div height in Sync with another div (content reactive)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I'm working on a side panel component that I can shrink or enlarge its width.
I am using Vue.js.

The panel consists of a parent div called node-sidebar-panel and two child divs: divider and sidebar-content. The sidebar-content div's height will depend on its content, and I don't know it in advance.

My goal is to make the divider div always have the same height as the sidebar-content div. I've attempted using flexbox and various CSS techniques, but I haven't found a working solution yet.

I also tried a JS approach to retrieve the scrollHeight value but the problem is that the scrollHeight is set to the max value of a previous interaction and not to the current.

So how can I make the divider div automatically adjust its height to match the sidebar-content div's height?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is a sample of my code :

```js
<template>
  <div class="node-sidebar" @mouseup="endDragging">
    <transition name="slide">
      <div v-if="isPanelOpen()" class="node-sidebar-panel" :style="{ width: panelWidth + 'px' }">
        <div class="divider"  @mousedown="startDragging"></div>
        <div class="sidebar-content"  ref="sidebarContent">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <table v-if="$store.state.currentNode.context">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Dims</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="context in currentNode.context.fields" :key="context.id">
                <td>{{ context.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ context.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ context.dims }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="bottom-margin"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, ref, watch, Ref } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { JsonTreeCustom } from "../jsontree/index";


const scrollHeightValue: Ref<number> = ref(0);


const isPanelOpen = () => {
  if (sidebarContent.value != null) {
    scrollHeightValue.value = sidebarContent.value.scrollHeight;
  }

  return store.state.isNodeSidePanelOpen;
};

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../../vars.sass";

//...

.node-sidebar-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-left: 2px solid $background-color;
  box-shadow: -6px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100%;
}

.divider {
  width: 1%;
  background-color: red;

  cursor: ew-resize;
}
.sidebar-content {
  width: 99%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}


</style>
```

And here a screenshot : You can see that the content overflow the sidebar-content div after an height greater than at least 100vh.

The divider div is red and content is blue. The divider div is used to shrink the width of my panel

[image: screenshot]